# How to show the numbering for subticks in log scaled plot?

Tags: qt, axis, qt5, qcustomplot

I am using **qCustomPlot** library to plot graph. I would like to show the subticks' numbering on the log scaled graph.

```
customPlot->xAxis->setSubTickCount(8);
customPlot->xAxis->setScaleType(QCPAxis::stLogarithmic);          
customPlot->xAxis->setScaleLogBase(10);
```

With the code, I just able to show labels for major ticks, for eg. (10, 100, 1000, 10000). However, I would like to show the numbering for subticks as well. For example, between the major ticks 10 and 100, I wanna show 20, 30, 50. How should I do that? Or it's not possible to show subticks' labels with **qCustomPlot**?

Thanks in advance.